# TFS Not Asking for Location to save Project and Not Saving Correct Project Name (Visual Studio 2015)

Tags: vb.net, tfs, version-control, visual-studio-2015

So I've been working with Visual Studio 2010 in a VB.Net environment for a couple of years now and I have never experienced this issue previously. When I create a new project and save it to Source Control (TFS) it would ask me where I would like to save my project, first locally and then in Source Control.

Now I am currently using Visual Studio 2015 and what happened to me recently is that after I create a new project and save it to Source Control, it does not prompt me to save the project locally.  It does end up saving it to Source Control, but not under the name that I changed it to.

One thing I was considering was that when I create a new project, I do not name the project right away.  I use a template with a generic name.  When I am done with the project, I then give it a name.  When I check Source control to locate the project, I see the Generic name of the template I used instead of the name that I changed the project to.  I also noticed that often need to manually change the Assembly Name from $safeprojectname$ (don't remember exactly) to my new project name.

Sequence of Events:
A.  Open new project
B.  Choose template (do not change name)
C.  Create Project
D.  Finish Project (change name of project including Assembly Name)
E.  Add to Source Control

Is there a way that I can:

1. Have project name be the name that I changed it to instead of the generic name of the template?
2. Have Visual Studio prompt me to choose file locations for when I save locally and in Source Control?

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? I believe the Visual Studio 2015 application doesn't support TFS anymore, with the idea of people to moving to TFTS (Team Foundation Team Services) previous VSO (Visual Studio Online)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a project in VS, you can select or browse the Location to choose your local location:

[image]

Regarding the location in TFS, it depends on which team project you are connecting, and which workspace your team project is using.

If misunderstanding anything, you can attach some screenshots so that we can understand better for your issue.

Comment: A brief update:  So I realized that my procedure for creating a new project needed to be changed.  Previously, I was able to rename my project at the end of the process and I also mapped the location of the project locally.  Now, when I a create a New Project, I must rename my project and set the local file path.  When I change my procedure, I see my project with the correct name.  I believe my other issue has to deal the the workspce my team project is using.  Perhaps something has changed.  I am trying to track down the difference.  Thanks for the input so far I'll try to give screenshots.

Comment: So doing some more research, I found that I was able to go back to how I was previously creating projects.  In Tools>>Options>>Projects and Solutions>>General, there is an checkbox that allows you to save new projects when created.  Previously, mines was checked.  I unchecked it, and now when I create a project, it does not save the Generic template I used and it lets me chose the location when I add it to Source Control.